# while page display when calling php page in android application using WiFi IP address

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse, webview

I'm calling PHP page from my android application using Webview control, but it displaying white page only. my mobile and pc are connected to USB data cable and both are having the same wifi connection. I've used ipconfig command and copied ipv4 IP address in code. I've given all the required permission in manifest file in eclipse.

my android code as follows:

> // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2

```
  browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // Enable javascript
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

    // Set WebView client
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                }
        });
     // Load the webpage
    browser.loadUrl("http://192.168.2.7/tendersystem/webservice/display_category.php");
```

---

I can see ouptput in laptop using above path, but when running in android using datacable gettign white page only in webview control. so, whta's the problem???

If I'm using online url like http://www.google.com , it is displaying properly but ip address doing problem.

Comment: try to open this link in your mobile's browser like chrome or any other app

Comment: try adding port number after ip address

Comment: Now error is , The webpage at http://192.168.2.7/tendersystem/webservice/display_category.php could not be loaded because :   net:: ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT

Comment: browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);